# Lumen - Registering Class in Service Provider

Tags: php, laravel, aop, lumen, goaop

I am registering an Aspect class in the AopServiceProvider. However, it does not seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
public function register()
{
     $this->app->singleton(LoggingAspect::class, function (Application $app) {
        return new LoggingAspect($app->make(LoggerInterface::class));
    });

    $this->app->tag([LoggingAspect::class], 'goaop.aspect');
}
```

Now even if I have the code as this:

```
public function register()
{
     $this->app->singleton(LogsasasagingAspect::class, function (Application $app) {
        return new LoggingAspect($app->make(LoggesasarInterface::class));
    });

    $this->app->tag([LoggasaingAspect::class], 'goaop.aspect');
}
```

It still doesn't show any error.

This service provider has been registered as:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AopServiceProvider::class);
```

Is this normal or is there any fix for this?

Comment: if you put a `dd('foobar')` in the register function, does it show?

Comment: Yes, It shows as string(6) "foobar".

Comment: 'It does not seem to work': what doesn't?

Comment: I do not get an error for invalid class name and the aspect portion doesn't work for the valid classes.

Comment: So what error does it throw when you use the aspect portion? Sorry, but your question is vague and your posted code seems absolutely fine so your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: It doesn't show any error. I have followed the steps from here https://github.com/goaop/goaop-laravel-bridge .

Comment: Okay that's cool. But post code relevant to the problem and explain it more thoroughly then. What do you expect your code to do and what does it actually do? If it doesn't show errors, you've probably made a business logic mistake that isn't visible here.